# Are there any good web apps for Twitter for Businesses?

Tags: twitter, webapp-rec

I'm looking for the best Twitter-based web app that can be used by a fairly high-profile business.

I'd prefer to use a web app rather than a client app because it may need to be managed from various places.

It needs to be able to manage (tweet from) multiple Twitter accounts (company and individuals), keep track of a number of searches, and have an easy-to-use UI for non technophiles.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Community Wiki?

Comment: @rchern - I don't think it really qualifies for Community Wiki personally...

Comment: There isn't a single objective answer to this question.  See http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/423/is-asking-is-there-a-webapp-for-x-on-topic

Comment: That thread talks about whether they're on topic, and the consensus seems to be that they are and that they're very valuable. The only mention of Community Wiki is one comment. But hey, I'm happy to change it if people object to leaving it as is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You definitely cannot go past [CoTweet](http://cotweet.com/)! They compete directly with HootSuite.

[image: CoTweet promo image]
<sub>(source: [cotweet.com](http://cotweet.com/images/_site/feature_tab1.jpg))</sub>

Features include:

- Multiple Accounts and Multiple Users
- Monitor Keywords and Trends
- On Duty Notifications
- Conversation Threading
- Click Tracking
- Tweet Scheduling
- Multi-Account Posting
- Message Archive

**CoTweet is used by some of the biggest brands, including Microsoft, McDonalds, Pepsi and Coca Cola!**

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but this reads a lot like an advertisement... do you have any connection with the company?

Comment: Nope - none whatsover, and sorry if it sounded that way! I was just trying to convey what I think makes it good. If I ever have any commercial association with anything that I am talking about I will be sure to give a proper disclosure.

Comment: @tobeannounced - no problem, just thought I'd check!

Comment: +1 for CoTweet.  One of the best designed webapps I've ever used.  

I don't believe they were acquired by HootSuite though - they were acquired by ExactTarget and *compete* with HootSuite:

http://blog.cotweet.com/2010/03/cotweet-connects-with-exacttarget/

Comment: @3rdparty - Woops, yes you are right! Sorry, I went off my memory as I thought I had read that on TechCrunch a while ago. Thanks for pointing it out, I have fixed the post.

Comment: May have to down-vote my own answer here - as our young SEO/Social Media wizz-kid @ramafon seems to love CoTweet. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

[HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com/) springs to mind, there are social management tools from [SalesForce](http://www.salesforce.com/crm/customer-service-support/social-networking/) as well.

Although personally I would use [TweetDeck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/) and if you want to keep it in-sync between machines, create a login with them.

Comment: +1 for HootSuite, it's perfect, I think you can even assign an account to someone without giving them the password.